# Clash of clan style login - Android and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, game-center

Im working on a game for both of these platforms and just wanted some help in understanding how Clash of Clans manage to log into their web service without the user ever entering in a username and password. Are they saving some other data into their database that is specific to the device that it is being used on? On iOS, what I thought was happening was that the game would retrieve the login details from Game center in an OAuth connection but I don't think that's the case anymore what with the user not needing any sort of account login on Android Devices.

Anyway my question is how do you think they are achieving this or how could I achieve something similar to this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be too broad as I have stated the specific question and ways that I thought it had been done. I just wanted to know of different ways in which this could be achieved. Are there really that many different ways that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I also think questions sometimes get closed for the wrong reason. Anyway, your login and password is stored on the device. LibGDX has `Preferences` where you could store those. But you do have to salt the password there and decrypt it on the server side.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I'm trying not to store any username and password anywhere, in fact I don't even want the user to enter in any of these ever (Even on first opening). Instead what I want is, like a game like Clash of clans where it seems to store some details, be that the device being used or an account  (Apple Gamecenter account) and uses this to retrieve the user's details

Comment: You always need to store something... perhaps you want to store just the user name or `userxxxxxxxx` and link that to something like facebook. When that link is made the user can auto log in. What I did for a client/server game is let the user press `play` and it creates a guest account. From there the user could register with email. On the server side I used a SQL database to check credentials.

Comment: I'm aware about needing to store some sort of data, I like the idea of the guest account as the user doesn't need to enter in any information themselves and can get straight to playing the game. To keep going back to the example (Clash of clans), if you start the game fresh right now, it will not ask you for any data but yet still know the user and their data then next time they open the app. I'm looking currently at the class "IdentifierForVendor" in the apple API and storing that unique string in my database instead. Maybe there could be something similar for Androids aswell?

Comment: I would really just use my own player ID and store it using Preferences. Then give the player an option or even reward to somehow link or register the account.

Comment: If I cant find a way to do this, I think I will do it that way, I think giving incentives for it could be a good idea

Comment: With Apple's Game Center service, the API allows you to save game data on GC server or your own server.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I've decided to do this through a token login. Basically what happens is when a user first opens the app the server will generate a token and send that back to the user. I store this token so that in future whenever a user does anything in the game, this token gets sent along with it. I think to make it more secure I will ask for the persons name, or make it default to anon and maybe store and check against this as well. Eventually I will allow users to link this account to another (Facebook, Google, game centre)